# private constructor and static constructor in singleton pattern

Tags: constructor, singleton

I'm a c# developer.

I have confused with private constructor and static constructor in singleton pattern.

Here is my sample code in below:

standard singleton pattern and it is thread safe:

```
public class SingletonTest
{
    private static readonly Lazy<RedisCacheManager> CacheManager = new Lazy<RedisCacheManager>(() => new RedisCacheManager());

    /// <summary>
    /// singleton pattern
    /// </summary>
    private SingletonTest() { }

    public static RedisCacheManager Instance
    {
        get { return CacheManager.Value; }
    }
}
```

second it changed the private constructor to static constructor:

```
public class SingletonTest
{
    private static readonly Lazy<RedisCacheManager> CacheManager = new Lazy<RedisCacheManager>(() => new RedisCacheManager());

    /// <summary>
    /// static(single object in our application)
    /// </summary>
    static SingletonTest() { }

    public static RedisCacheManager Instance
    {
        get { return CacheManager.Value; }
    }
}
```

And my question is the second code still one of the singleton pattern or just it always keep a only one object(RedisCacheManager) in our application?
Somebody help me,thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'static constructor'.

Comment: look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to answer you question, we need to go to basic.

> Static constructors have the following properties:
>
> 1. A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are
>    referenced.
> 2. A static constructor cannot be called directly.
> 3. If a static constructor throws an exception, the runtime will not invoke it a second time, and the type will remain uninitialized for
>    the lifetime of the application domain in which your program is
>    running.

But for standard singleton pattern

> 1. It will be loaded, when we call it. So we have control over, when the singleton object will be created.
> 2. User has complete control when to call it.

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: So both of them keep a one instance in our application within the application life time.static instance is created by  translater when project started,and singleton instance is created when we called it?

Comment: yes for static we do not have any control, but for instance we have